# Insert values through getchar

Tags: c

I am unable to insert a value into ptr char array:

```
int main() {

  char S[MAX_STRING_LENGTH],*str;

  int total,j=0,i=0;
  char ptr[16],c;

    scanf("%d",&total);

      for(i=0;i<total;i++){
          c=getchar();
           do{

           ptr[j]=(char)tolower(c);
           j++;
           c=getchar();
           }while(c!='\n' && j<15 );

           ptr[j]='\0';
           printf("j=%d , %s",j,ptr);
           }

}
```

The reason for this I know:

I put do-loop exit on '\n' and I'm using enter('\n') itself after inserting value in total.
That way it is exiting loop without insertion of value.

How can I correct it?

Comment: You should also limit your do-while loop to maximum of 15 iterations (`c != '\n' && j < 15`). Right now you're able to write beyond array bound.

Comment: even these corrections are not giving me the answer

Comment: To be proper, you should take into account the fact that `getchar()`'s return type is `int`, *not* `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `scanf` did scan `\n` in the input stream but it didn't store it in `&total` . The next time you `getchar()` it will get it `\n`which cause the do-while only can execute once.
add

```
getchar();
```

after scanf.

input stream :

```
            the next you getchar() will from here
             |
             | 
A A A A A A \n A A A A A A
          ^
          |
  the variable total store string before this
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it will execute while loop only once.?

Comment: @VallabhPatade `\n` doesn't store it in `&total` but it was in input stream,next time you will first get it immediately

Comment: You mean if there is something in inputstream, getchar() doesn't wait for user' action and will read \n\ and will go ahed ending the loop after first iteration.?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is kind of unsafe. First of all depending on the operating system you may have to terminate on '\r' not only on '\n'. Second you never check the size of the input to be within 15 symbols. Please note I say **15 symbols** because it is usually good practise to leave one cell for the zero terminating character.

If the input does not contain whitespaces(space or tab) I would advice you to use `scanf("%s")` as it is less error-prone. Also you will eliminate the need for a while loop.

If that is not the case, you should add a check for '\r' as well and also you will have to remove the newline character that you type after the total value. Like so:

```
scanf("%d", &total);
getchar();
```

This is needed because otherwise the newline after total will be the first char you read in your while loop and thus you will exit on the first iteration of the cycle.

If you debug your program you will see that this happens.

Answer (score 0):

During scanf you will enter some no(no of characters) say 10 and will hit enter. Now this '\n\ will not be read by scanf and it's there in input stream. During first iteration, getchar() will read this '\n' and will terminate the loop after first iteration. So better put a getchar() after scanf() so as no make inputstream to empty. apart from this,

You haven't put any check beyond array index limit. It maybe the case user keep entering the characters and you endup trying to insert beyond 16 places.

```
 while(c != '\n' && j < 15);
```

Will solve your problem.

Comment: Actaully the first version of your comment conatained a bit more of the solution. scanf really does not read the newline and this causes a single iteration when reading in the loop.

Comment: Yeah I got that was confused between behaviour of getchar() and scanf(). I have edited my post.

Comment: yes I have seen this and what  am saying is that the first version also held part of the answer.

Comment: if i only want abc to enter into ptr then it will show me abcxvxvxcvx.. as loop is going till 15 and string end char would be at 16 , so the string length will become 16 not 3 which i want.

Comment: @izomorphius I have edited the post accordingly. Earlier wasn't considering the first scenarion. Thanks for pointing it out.